# Bitcoin transaction priority calculation

Tags: transaction-selection, coin-age-priority

From the Bitcoin wiki [page on transaction fees](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Technical_info):

> Transaction priority is calculated as a value-weighted sum of input
>   age, divided by transaction size in bytes:
>
> priority = sum(input_value_in_base_units * input_age)/size_in_bytes
>   Transactions need to have a priority above 57,600,000 to avoid the
>   enforced limit

Can somebody clarify what input_value_in_base_units or input_age is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`input_value_in_base_units` is the number of satoshis that the input is worth. One Bitcoin is worth 100,000,000 satoshis.

`input_age` is how many blocks the input has been present for. An unconfirmed transaction has an age of 0, and one that has 100 confirmations has an age of 100.