# What determines the order of transactions in a block?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, mining-theory, transaction-selection, getblocktemplate

I've been looking at the live mempool on mempool.space, and while most transactions are sorted in order of highest sat/vB to lowest, I've noticed some that standout with extremely high sat/vB but are placed further back in the block.

I've tried looking for reasons why, such as a parent-child dependency, but I couldn't figure it out.

What exactly determines this ordering? I'm wondering what the incentive of agreeing to a much higher rate is, if your transaction will be fulfilled later than others in the block, or potentially even pushed back to the next one.

Comment: You tagged the question bitcoin-core, can you confirm you want to know specifically how bitcoin core's [`getblocktemplate`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblocktemplate.html) selects and orders transactions rather than how other mining software and other algorithms work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does getblocktemplate use priority for transaction selection?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46185/why-does-getblocktemplate-use-priority-for-transaction-selection)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I don’t think that’s related. Coin-age priority was disabled by default in Bitcoin Core v0.12

Comment: Pieter's answer does mention that the priority based selection was replaced by a CPFP algorithm.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick that post helped me deepen my understanding a lot, thanks. I think my question has been answered. Additionally, I realized that I was looking at the fee rate, when the effective fee rate is what's being used to order the transactions in most cases.